# equisetum and soil pH

Tags: soil, soil-amendment

To make my garden soil less acidic, I have sprayed a 1 percent aqueous solution of dolomite to control the spread of horsetail. Will this measure help me achieve the desired result?

Comment: @PatrickB. I understand now. My concern was that "snob" is a slightly derogatory term in English, so it shouldn't be in a post to begin with (except perhaps in a question on a language Q&A site). In future, please edit out off-topic sections like that. The OP can post them in a comment (with suitably toned-down language) if they wish.

Comment: Did you get a message that this question "doesn't meet the quality standards?". That's an automated check that has more to do with the length of the post (which is easy for a computer to check) than grammar (which isn't). A very short question can indicate that more detail about the problem is needed in order to be able to provide a good, specific, answer

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this solution will have any effect. This is based on my experience where I live so there is still a possibility it will work. Gardening is not a science and results differ widely due to climate, soil types and variation within a species.

- trying to change the ph of your soil by applying acid or alkaline solutions will only cause a short term change in the soil conditions. Unless you amend the soil and add lime or acid yearly pH changes will be minimal
- where I live I am surrounded by limestone. The soil is alkaline and the groundwater is alkaline.  The equisetum in my garden seems quite vigorous at a soil pH of 7.1.

This [answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/19740/499) on control methods may be helpful.