# How to get rid of horse tails from the garden?

Tags: weed-control

Has anyone been successful in getting rid of [**horse tail weed**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equisetum) in an environmentally safe way? It's starting to sprout in many places. If I pull out one, 5 start to grow in the same place.

Comment: Given "environmentally safe way", this might be a better question / answers to look at, rather than one that's "Poison A or Poison B", as the linked question/answers are.  http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/19740/my-new-allotment-plot-is-covered-in-horsetail